# Some kind of loop error in java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I've created an arraylist in java which shows a bunch of stuff.The program runs the way i want but i've a little inconvenience.at the end of the loop below it displays this : A@

```
ArrayList umudo = new ArrayList();
   while(true){
    int n2 = readInt("Enter the block: ");   
       int le=dyibul.modulo(n2, de, n);


       if(dyibul.numdigits(le)==3){
           int me= (le/100);
           int ne=  le-me*100;
           char y = (char) (me+65);
           char z = (char) (ne+65);
           String bu=(y+""+z);
           umudo.add(bu);

       }else{
           int me= (le/100);
           int ne=  le-me*100;
           char y = (char) (me+65);
           char z = (char) (ne+65);
           String bu2=(y+""+z);

           umudo.add(bu2);
       }


       if(n2==-1){
           break;
       }

       }
        for(int j=0;j<umudo.size();j++){

           print(umudo.get(j));

       }
```

I suppose it's something to do with the place it's stored or sth.But i don't want it to appear.Can you give me a clue?

Edit:umudo is the name of my ArrayList.Java compiler isn't giving any red lined error alert.and my ArrayList consists of Strings.This is the final step of my RSA decoding/hacking homework.

Comment: What's umdo? What data structure is it? What does it contain? Add the declaration snippet of umdo.

Comment: show more code? Maybe the contents of the set/list

Comment: I suspect it is either from umudo itself or in your print method, because nothing is wrong per say with your loop.  Please show more code.

Comment: btw: Why don't you use the simplified for-loop `for (Umu umu: umudo) print (umu);` ? What does umudo (j).toString () return? How is print defined?

Comment: umudo.get() returns parts of the decoding and in for loop they combine together and form the secret message sent in words.i don't know about the kind of for loop notation you used (user unknown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are *expecting* the output to be.

However, this is most likely wrong:

```
   if(dyibul.numdigits(le)==3){
       int me= (le/100);
       int ne=  le-me*100;
       char y = (char) (me+65);
       char z = (char) (ne+65);
       String bu=(y+""+z);
       umudo.add(bu);
   }else{
       int me= (le/100);
       int ne=  le-me*100;
       char y = (char) (me+65);
       char z = (char) (ne+65);
       String bu2=(y+""+z);
       umudo.add(bu2);
   }
```

The code in the *then* and *else* blocks is identical.

Comment: Thank you very much,it solved the problem.I know it was the stupidest question,but i'm new into this kinda stuff.